# Django | Why are my added fields to my CreateView not saved to the database/ or aren't rendered?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

For a couple of days I'm stuck on a part of my Django project, where I want to add some extra fields for the user to fill in when they create a post. The problem is that the extra fields are not showing up on the page, or are saved in the database. I'm seeing these added fields on the create post template, so they are showing up and I can use them in the form (I'm using Cripsy forms), but after submitting, its not being saved (or something?) I'm using the CreateView and use a ModelForm to add those fields. I've followed all of the steps from the Django documentation but I can't solve it.

I'm still a beginner, but I've looked everywhere for answers but nowhere I can find a specific solution to this problem.

Please take a look at my code.

I'm using the Django Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I've added a forms.py file where my ModelForm is located which holds the extra fields:

```
class AddPostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # forms.ModelForm i.p.v. forms.Form omdat ik gebruik maak van een Model: Post
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '40'}))
    tip = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment', 'tip']
```

And I'm using the CreateView where I'm saying which ModelForm is used:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = AddPostCreateForm
    # fields = ['title', 'content', 'tip'] Deze fields zijn volgens mij niet meer nodig omdat die uit forms.py komen
    #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html <-- Zo zoekt django standaard naar templates
    # De bovenstaande viewtype is in dit geval create, maar django zoekt op: post
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Dit zegt dat de auteur van de post de ingelogde gebruiker moet zijn
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is my template where my posts are rendered and where the post fields of title and content are showing up, but the added form fields 'tip' and 'comment' are not saved.

```
{% for post in posts %}
      <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="media-body">
              <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                  <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
              </div>
              <!-- De post.id is de parameter voor de url -->
              <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
              <p class="article-content">{{ post.comment }}</p>
              <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
              <p class="article-content">{{ post.tip }}</p>
          </div>
      </article>
  {% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure which part I'm doing wrong, my guess is that it's not being saved to the database so that I can't use the variables in the template. But perhaps I'm not using them right in the template. Please let me know how to solve this, or what I'm doing wrong. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: BTW: The indentation of the classes are correct, not like its showing here.

Comment: You do't have `tip` and `comment` fields in your Model. These are only present in the form, that is why you see them in the form but they have not saved in db. So add these fields to your model and it will be work.

Comment: @NKSM Alright, that made me think about 2 things. 1: that makes sense, because the model is directly connected to the databas, but I thought by specifying in the ModelForm which model I wanted to use, that would take care of it? But that is not the case then. And 2: Why would I now want to make use of a ModelForm instead of just adding those fields to the Post model? Thank you for you answer, I'm going to make those changes. But to be clear, what are the field-types going to be in the Post-model?